# How would you optimize this simple but slow Python 'for' loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, iteration

Basically, I have a function that, for each row, sums one extra value above at a time until the sum reaches a given threshold. Once it reaches the given threshold, it takes the resulting slice index and uses it to return the mean of that slice of another column.

```
import numpy as np

#Random data:
values = np.random.uniform(0,10,300000)
values2 = np.random.uniform(0,10,300000)
output = [0]*len(values)

#Function that operates one one single row and returns the mean
def function(threshold,row):
    slice_sum=0
    i=1
    while slice_sum < threshold:
        slice_sum = values[row-i:row].sum()
        i=i+1        
    mean = values2[row-i:row].mean()
    return mean


#Loop to iterate the function row by row:
for i in range(15,len(values)): #let's just skip the first 15 values, otherwise the loop might get stuck. This issue is not prioritary though.
    output[i] = function(40,i)
```

This is a simplified version of the loop. It might not look slow, but it is very slow for all intents and practical purposes. So I'm wondering if there's a faster way of achieving this without a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: Just to simplify the question, you don't need to preallocate `output` to any certain length. Just use `output = [function(40, i) for i in range(15, len(values))]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to recompute the sum each time through the loop. You are starting with `values[row-1:row]` (a single value), and if that is small enough, adding an additional value. Rather than re-summing the same values iteration after iteration, just augment the previous sum with the next value.

```
def function(threshold, row):
    slice_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, len(values)+1):
        slice_sum += values[row-i]
        if slice_sum >= threshold:
            break
    return values2[row-i-1:row].mean()
```

This reduces the number of addition operations from O(n^2) to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Use searchsorted on a cumulative sum of `values` to navigate directly to the next group. This will give you O(n log n) performance where n is the number of groups in values:

```
import numpy as np

def meanBlocks(values,values2,threshold):
    sums = np.cumsum(values)
    i = j = k = 0
    output = np.zeros(values.size)
    while j < values.size:
        s = sums[j]-values[j]+threshold     # s is next cumsum to reach
        i,j = j,np.searchsorted(sums,s)     # position of next increment by threshold 
        output[k] = np.mean(values2[i:j])   # track mean of values2 for range
        k += 1
    return output[:k]
```

outputs:

```
values  = np.arange(10)
values2 = np.arange(10)*5
print(values)
print(values2)
print(meanBlocks(values,values2,13))

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]           #   (0+1+2+3+4)    (5+6)     (7)   ...   
[ 0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45] # (0,5,10,15,20)  (25,30)    (35)  ...
[10.  27.5 35.  40.  45. ]      #   50/5 = 10    55/2=27.5    35   ...


print("")
values    = np.random.uniform(0,10,300000)
values2   = np.random.uniform(0,10,300000)
print(values)
print(values2)
print(meanBlocks(values,values2,40)) # takes 0.43 sec on my laptop

[6.79333765 2.22880971 1.37706989 ... 8.75649835 2.92422716 5.1280224 ]
[3.56901367 0.15243962 6.76291706 ... 4.47662928 2.61969948 8.0941208 ]
[4.88477774 3.87464821 5.42599828 ... 4.47055786 4.48768768 5.17582407]
```